# Imposing/ensuring a constant mass flow rate in turbulent flow simulation

Tags: fluid-mechanics, finite-element-method, cfd, turbulence

I'm trying to simulate using Finite Elements (non commercial software) the Tube Bundle benchmark problem:
[http://cfd.mace.manchester.ac.uk/ercoftac/doku.php?id=cases:case078&s[]=tube&s[]=bundle](http://cfd.mace.manchester.ac.uk/ercoftac/doku.php?id=cases:case078&s%5B%5D=tube&s%5B%5D=bundle)

Many authors (e.g. ***Benchmark Simulation of Turbulent Flow through a Staggered Tube Bundle to Support CFD as a Reactor Design Tool. Part II: URANS CFD Simulation***) have used a single periodic cell (the right picture in Fig. 1) as their computational domain, with periodic boundary conditions. To maintain the flow rate, they impose a constant, prescribed flow rate via pressure gradient/body source term.

Here is where I would appreciate some help. I have a math background, and I was not able to find any literature that explains how exactly this is done. The trial-and-error approach didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in OpenFOAM using `meanVelocityForce` momentum source, which applies a force to maintain a user-specified volume-averaged mean velocity.

You can find details about the mean velocity force momentum source in [here](https://www.openfoam.com/documentation/guides/latest/doc/guide-fvoptions-sources-mean-velocity-force.html) and [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332441950_Implementing_streamwise_periodic_boundary_condition_in_OpenFOAM).

I played around and simulated the tube bundle described in the paper you linked (with no turbulence modelling), using `cyclicAMI` boundary conditions and `meanVelocityForce` as an fvOption:

```
momentumSource
{
    type            meanVelocityForce;

    selectionMode   all;

    fields          (U);
    Ubar            (0 0.01 0);
}
```

And got some nice results, so I believe it should work with you too.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, I am not using OpenFOAM.

Answer (score 0):

One implementation is given in

*Large eddy simulations of incompressible turbulent flows using
parallel computing techniques*, Int. J. Numer. Meth. Fluids 2008; 56:1819–1843, on pg. 1833.

In order to maintain the mass flow rate in the system equal to its initial value, a mean streamwise pressure gradient term $F^{n+1}\overrightarrow{e}_1$ is added to the streamwise momentum equation and is adjusted at each time step as

\begin{equation}
 F^{n+1} = F^n + \frac{1}{\tau}\left[ m^0  - 2m^n + m^{n-1}\right], 
\end{equation}

where $m^0$ is the initial bulk velocity multiplied by the size of the inlet and $\tau$ is a timestep.

Comment: Could you please elaborate & provide a summary of what is written in the book you referenced. Otherwise we have no way of knowing how appropriate your answer is.